numpy error when running python contract from algokit framework
when I tried to run my contract script into algokit project, it tell me this error message,
This come from the imported library numpy
numpy==2.0.0   algopy==0.6.1
>    
>     File "C:\Users\LocalUser\algo\.venv\Lib\site- 
  packages\algopy\__init__.py",
> line 72, in <module>     warnings.simplefilter("ignore",
> numpy.ComplexWarning)                                    
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
   AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute
> 'ComplexWarning'
> 
> ```


Edit the question to show the complete error message (i.e. the complete traceback), and also state which versions of algopy and numpy you are using.

It looks like algopy needs to be updated to handle some changes that have occurred in  NumPy 2.0.  In particular, ComplexWarning is only available as numpy.exceptions.ComplexWarning.  You might be able to work around this by downgrading numpy to version 1.26.4.

How can I downgrade numpy

I try to install this version of numpy pip install numpy==1.6.2

and its tell me this error message
import imp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Why version 1.6.2?  Did you try 1.26.4?

https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.6.2/ the version 1.62 isnt available since a while

oh sorry I try the 1.26.4

https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.26.4/

Okay it<s now runable thank you

its still showing an error there it is

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\LocalUser\Documents\Sidechain_algorand\Blockchain\projects\Keraneum-contracts\smart_contracts\blockchain_dapp\contract.py", line 1, in 
from algopy import ARC4Contract, String
ImportError: cannot import name 'ARC4Contract' from 'algopy' (C:\Users\LocalUser\Documents\Sidechain_algorand.venv\Lib\site-packages\algopy_init_.py)

It appears you mistakenly installed algopy instead of algokit.
Possible fix:
pip uninstall algopy
pip install algorand-python

